Is there an Apple TV app that lets you locally store videos/photos to watch offline?
I'm talking about an app that is like the "Files app" on iOS, or anything alike. I just have some videos that are on my MacBook that I would like to have stored on my Apple TV to watch them offline without any internet connection at all. I have the 4th Generation Apple TV. Is this possible?
If not, I was thinking of maybe buying the 3rd generation Apple TV, could it be easier to locally store files there? How could that work as well?

AFAIK, no.  End users are not allowed access to the local storage. You can stream from your Mac (push or pull), or AirPlay from a phone with local files, but you can’t write to the local storage.

@jimtut does AirPlay use bandwidth, can it slow down the internet speed if it's a local file being AirPlayed?

No. It uses the local network, not your internet connection.

Thanks for the info @jimtut
